# Get the name of array in array?

Tags: arrays, node.js

How can I get the string name 'bar' instead of its contents ?
Never found a solution for this one?
I want console.log("?") to say 'bar'

```
let foo = [1,2,3], bar = [11,22,33], hello = [111,222,333]
    let arr = [foo, bar, hello]
    console.log(arr[1])
    // returns 11, 22, 33  ** I know this
    // I want it to return "bar" ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above, you can't do this the way it is.

You could however, attach a name property to each base array.

For example:

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3], arr2 = [2,3,4];
arr1.name = "arr1";
arr2.name = "arr2";

const arrBoth = [arr1, arr2];

console.log(arrBoth[0].name);
```

Comment: Ah, that does look like it will make more sense this way if I can adjust the way I think about this problem.  Sometimes you just need another perspective thats half the reason these sites are so helpful. Thanks. Ps. please give upTicks to those in need!! ))

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot do that. You might need to use an object for that